# How do I solve FirebaseAuth isAnonymous return false on an Anonymous user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I logged in as Anonymous user. See my Firebase console screenshot:

[image]

But when I checked by printing the status like this:

```
print('Is Anonymous:
 ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.isAnonymous}. UID: ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid}');
```

This is what I got in debug console:

```
I/flutter (12139): Is Anonymous: false. UID: O75s04Y3voRTdqaUJJ5gdyinQSB3
```

How can it be?
Is there anyone ever had this kind of problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually check the [`user.providerData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/providerData.html) to determine if the user is associated with any providers. If not, I consider it anonymous.

In another app I only care about Google sign-in, and use this:

```
bool isSignedInUser() {
  return this.user != null && (
    this.user.providerData.any((UserInfo info) => info.providerId == "google.com")
  );
}
```

Comment: So does it mean that it is better not to rely on the getter `isAnonymous` ?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You're saying that `isAnonymous` doesn't work for your purpose, so I recommend checking the provider data to see if that _does_ work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is, it does work most of the time. But somehow it is not 100% reliable. Some unknown strange cases like the above happens. Not sure how to reproduce it though. So does this means that the `isAnonymous` method works in  different way than `providerData.any` ?